# Setting up Android Studio project with Git

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm trying to learn how to properly use Git to manage an Android project. I'm using Android Studio (1.0.2).

Specifically, I'm trying to create a system by which when I create a new Android project, I want to ensure that I am not including with future commits alterations to files that are unrelated to that commit (obviously, the point of Git). My approach thus far has been to go through the process of building, assembling debug and release versions of the app, etc to understand what files get generated for the first time and/or get altered with subsequent builds/assembles.

Do you think this is a good approach? Below are my main questions and outline of my process. Any comments on what is good practice when building/assembling are much much appreciated, I'm just trying to learn :)

=============================================================

**Commits**

```
$ git log --oneline
ad69b04 Added another constant to MainActivity
7111a61 Added constant to MainActivity
1066f5a initial clean, build, assembleDebug, assembleRelease
44a8136 init VCS in AS
384e286 git init
```

=============================================================

**Commit descriptions (from bottom to top)**

```
384e286 git init
```

I initialize git with "git init" and import a customized .gitignore (which is the default + some extra text files that I use for organization). Nothing much here.

---

```
44a8136 init VCS in AS
```

I hit VCS>Enable VCS... in Android Studio.

---

```
1066f5a initial clean, build, assembleDebug, assembleRelease
```

I execute "gradle clean" "gradle build" "gradle assembleDebug", "gradle assembleRelease". Below are the changes made to app/app.iml. **My Question: when will app.iml get updated? What changes cause app.iml to change?**

```
diff --git a/app/app.iml b/app/app.iml
index a07fb8c..c6c55c4 100644
--- a/app/app.iml
+++ b/app/app.iml
@@ -79,6 +79,7 @@
       <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/rs" />
       <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/symbols" />
       <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/outputs" />
+      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp" />
```

---

```
ad69b04 Added another constant to MainActivity
7111a61 Added constant to MainActivity
```

These baffled me. My goal was to just alter the activity and see if anything changed. After the first constant, something did! (below) However after adding another constant, nothing changed in my workspace (except the expected MainActivity).

```
commit 7111a61a48e68555ce5d5914647291bd0a0a026b
Author: Tom McFarlin <tmcfarlin@usgbc.org>
Date:   Thu Feb 5 18:50:12 2015 -05005039ac7b5e
Author: Tom McFarlin <tmcfarlin@usgbc.org>
    Added constant to MainActivity500

diff --git a/.idea/misc.xml b/.idea/misc.xml
index fba7e70..58ff01f 100644
--- a/.idea/misc.xml
+++ b/.idea/misc.xml
@@ -1,5 +1,8 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project version="4">
+  <component name="EntryPointsManager">
+    <entry_points version="2.0" />
+  </component>
```

What is "EntryPointsManager"? When does this change?

---

Any input is much appreciated! Thank you if you happen to read through all this.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `.gitignore` file specifically for Android Studio... You can find one such implementation here: https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514